# how to solve unregisterIRListener() in android

Tags: android, android-listview, listener

I am getting **D:/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called** log multiple times when i try to load data into a custom adapter. I don't know where is this issue and how to resolve it. Please help me to solve this issue.

**Code**

```
DatabaseDao dao = new DatabaseDao(context);
dataDao.open();
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = dataDao.getAllData();
dataDao.close();

int size = list.size();

if(size > 0) {
    DataAdapter adapter;
int index = 0;
DataClass data_list[] = new DataClass[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(i);
    DataClass dc;

    String data1, data2, data3;
    data1 = map.get("data1");
    data2 = map.get("data2");
    data3 = map.get("data3");

    dc = new DataClass(data1, data2, data3);
    data_list[index++] = dc;
}
adapter = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.list_data, data_list);
l1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Log**

```
03-19 14:04:19.679: D/AbsListView(431): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-19 14:04:19.699: D/AbsListView(431): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-19 14:04:19.699: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:19.729: D/AbsListView(431): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
03-19 14:04:19.729: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:19.819: D/libEGL(431): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): mem_init ++
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): gHwMemAllocator client 3
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): **** Using ION allocator ****
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): registered SIGUSR1[10] for pid[431]
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): HwMemAllocatorImpl[4fe03dcc] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/(431): mem_init 4fe03dcc--
03-19 14:04:19.829: D/ION(431): config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
03-19 14:04:19.869: D/MM_DEVICE(431): mm_device_thread starting
03-19 14:04:19.869: D/MM_DEVICE(431): Waiting for mm thread to come up
03-19 14:04:19.869: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglCreateContext() config: 18 context: 0x517776d0, VC context 1, Thread 431
03-19 14:04:19.879: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
03-19 14:04:19.879: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4fc0e6a8, VC surface: 1, Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:19.879: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(0x517776d0, 0x4fc0e6a8, 0x4fc0e6a8) Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:19.889: D/OpenGLRenderer(431): Enabling debug mode 0
03-19 14:04:19.889: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:20.069: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:20.069: D/WritingBuddyImpl(431): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
03-19 14:04:20.119: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:20.600: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:25.304: D/WritingBuddyImpl(431): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
03-19 14:04:25.414: D/WritingBuddyImpl(431): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
03-19 14:04:26.866: D/WritingBuddyImpl(431): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
03-19 14:04:26.866: D/WritingBuddyImpl(431): getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
03-19 14:04:28.647: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:29.949: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:30.339: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:34.834: D/AbsListView(431): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-19 14:04:35.004: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(431): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-19 14:04:35.074: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:35.074: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4fc0e6a8, android window 0x51779330, Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:35.504: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(0x517776d0, 0x4fbe4428, 0x4fbe4428) Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:35.504: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:35.534: D/AbsListView(431): onDetachedFromWindow
03-19 14:04:35.544: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(0x517776d0, 0x4fbe4428, 0x4fbe4428) Thread: 431
03-19 14:04:35.544: D/HAWAII_EGL(431): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 431
```

Comment: post your complete log

Comment: have added the complete logs.